# Platforms to Email connection

Tags: server, email, postfix

I have a domain name with GoDaddy and self-managed VPS (Ubuntu 14.10) with different company.

I'm still new when it comes to using anything but cPanel. If only I knew about the pure awesomeness of VPS and dedicated servers before GoDaddy lured me in with their overpriced shared hosting. =\

Anyway I'm trying to connect my domain email to VPS WordPress and other platforms in general. I want my domain email to work with registration, password recovery, custom forms etc.

I have tried installing postfix, dovecot and squarrelmail. After noobishly configuring it- I have finally managed to successfully send/receive mail by using squarrelmails web interface. Yet that didn't actually help me... WordPress & different platforms still didn't want to receive/send any emails.

I feel like I'm missing something extremely obvious. I only started working with Ubuntu 2 days ago and I still have a TON to learn. Most online tutorials make sense and everything is fine for the most part, yet I’m having quite a bit of trouble with email to platform connection.

Please let me know if you think you can give noobie a hand.

Thanks :)

P.S.
Sorry about using bunch of wrong terms, don't kick me hard.

Comment: You have a lot of questions there. Try starting with the ubuntu server guide and asking a more specific question. See http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/